# Replacing a set without clearing first

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using a JPA backed set.  So in order for the JPA provider not to delete all existing records and reinsert new ones I wanted to only reuse the values and remove the ones that really do not match.

Normally I would just do

```
mySet.clear();
mySet.addAll(newlyComputedSet());
```

But I was wondering if there was a good way of doing it without the `clear()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)): `mySet.retainAll(newlyComputedSet());`
Then [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

e.g.

```java
Set<X> newSet = newlyComputedSet();
mySet.retainAll(newSet);
mySet.addAll(newSet);
```